# Global variable is not inheriting from returned Firebase data (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, asynchronous, mapkit

I am trying to display a set of coordinates that I am reading from my firebase database. I retrieve the lat and long coordinates through function and assign it to a global variable so that I can call it to display on my maps. But the values are not being displayed, it displays the original values (0.0, 0.0) . I printed it out my results and the result are assigned to the global variables but it is not being inherited when I want to display it. What are some workarounds that I can implement or quick fixes ?

[image]

```
    var GPSlatdata = 0.0
    var GPSlongdata = 0.0

    func getlatitude(completion: @escaping (Double)->()){
        let ref = Database.database().reference()

        ref.child("GPSData/devices/1/latitude").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            if let latitudefire = snapshot.value as? Double
            {
                completion(latitudefire)
            }
        }
    }

    func getlongitude(completion: @escaping (Double)->()){
        let ref = Database.database().reference()

        ref.child("GPSData/devices/1/longitude").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            if let longitudefire = snapshot.value as? Double
            {
                completion(longitudefire)
            }
        }

    }

    getlatitude(completion: { (latx) in
        print("Before: \(GPSlatdata)")
        print("Recieved Lat Value: \(latx)")
        GPSlatdata = GPSlatdata + latx
        print("GPSlata data is = \(GPSlatdata)")
    })

    getlongitude(completion: { (longx) in
        print("Beforelong: \(GPSlongdata)")
        print("Recieved Lat Value: \(longx)")
        GPSlongdata = GPSlongdata + longx
        print("GPSlata data is = \(GPSlongdata)")
    })


    let skateboardposition = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: GPSlatdata, longitude: GPSlongdata)

    let skateboardposition = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: x1, longitude: x2)

    //just added
    let skateboardAnnotation = GPSAnnotation(coordinate: skateboardposition, title: "ACES Skaters", subtitle: "Current Board location - \nLatitude: \(GPSlatdata) Longitude: \(GPSlongdata)")

    GPSMap.addAnnotation(skateboardAnnotation)
    GPSMap.setRegion(skateboardAnnotation.region, animated: true)
```

Updated Changes: Still unable to plot the coordinates.

```
  import UIKit
  import Foundation
  import MapKit
  import Firebase

final class GPSAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
var title: String?
var subtitle: String?

init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String?, subtitle: String?)
{
    self.coordinate = coordinate
    self.title = title
    self.subtitle = subtitle

    super.init()
}

var region: MKCoordinateRegion{
    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05)
    return MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
}
}

 extension String {
func toDouble() -> Double? {
    return NumberFormatter().number(from: self)?.doubleValue
}
}



class GPSMapViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var GPSMap: MKMapView!


@IBOutlet weak var latLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var longLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let queue = DispatchGroup()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    var GPSlatdata = 0.0
    var GPSlongdata = 0.0

    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("GPSData/devices/1/latitude").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let latitudefire = snapshot.value as? Double
       {
        self.latLabel.text = "\(latitudefire)"
        }
    }

    ref.child("GPSData/devices/1/longitude").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let longitudefire = snapshot.value as? Double
        {

        self.longLabel.text = "\(longitudefire)"
        }
    }



    GPSMap.register(MKMarkerAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)


    func getlatitude(completion: @escaping (Double)->()){
        let ref = Database.database().reference()

        ref.child("GPSData/devices/1/latitude").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            if let latitudefire = snapshot.value as? Double
            {
                completion(latitudefire)
            }
        }
    }

    func getlongitude(completion: @escaping (Double)->()){
        let ref = Database.database().reference()

        ref.child("GPSData/devices/1/longitude").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            if let longitudefire = snapshot.value as? Double
            {
                completion(longitudefire)
            }
        }

    }

    queue.enter()
    getlatitude(completion: { (latx) in
        print("Before: \(GPSlatdata)")
        print("Recieved Lat Value: \(latx)")
        GPSlatdata = GPSlatdata + latx
        print("GPSlata data is = \(GPSlatdata)")
        queue.leave()
    })

    queue.enter()
    getlongitude(completion: { (longx) in
        print("Beforelong: \(GPSlongdata)")
        print("Recieved Lat Value: \(longx)")
        GPSlongdata = GPSlongdata + longx
        print("GPSlata data is = \(GPSlongdata)")
        queue.leave()
    })


    DispatchQueue.main.async{
    let skateboardposition = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: GPSlatdata, longitude: GPSlongdata)

   // let skateboardposition = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: x1, longitude: x2)
        print("The skateboard position is: \(skateboardposition)")
        print("GPSlatdata is: \(GPSlatdata)")
        print("GPSlongdata is: \(GPSlongdata)")        
  let skateboardAnnotation = GPSAnnotation(coordinate: skateboardposition, title: "ACES Skaters", subtitle: "Current Board location - \nLatitude: \(GPSlatdata) Longitude: \(GPSlongdata)")

        self.GPSMap.addAnnotation(skateboardAnnotation)
        self.GPSMap.setRegion(skateboardAnnotation.region, animated: true)
    }

}
}

extension GPSMapViewController: MKMapViewDelegate{
func GPSMap(_ GPSMap: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKMarkerAnnotationView?{
    if let GPSAnnotationView = GPSMap.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier) as? MKMarkerAnnotationView{
        GPSAnnotationView.animatesWhenAdded = true
        GPSAnnotationView.titleVisibility = .adaptive
        GPSAnnotationView.titleVisibility = .adaptive
    }
    return nil
}
}
```

Output: Still plotting the coordinates (0.0, 0.0)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not waiting for the completion handlers to finish. Completion handlers don't happen automatically - you have to wait for the data to be retrieved. Try using `DispatchGroup` so you can be sure of when the events are done.

```
let queue = DispatchGroup()

for i in 0..<5 {
    //Here we add a child into a queue
    queue.enter()
    print("Entering")
    //Start some action and wait for it to finish


    //... It finishes
    queue.leave()
    print("Leaving")

}

queue.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("We are done")
}
```

So in your case

```
let queue = DispatchGroup()

//Start an item
queue.enter()    
getlatitude(completion: { (latx) in
    print("Before: \(GPSlatdata)")
    print("Recieved Lat Value: \(latx)")
    GPSlatdata = GPSlatdata + latx
    print("GPSlata data is = \(GPSlatdata)")

    //we found latdata so leave
    queue.leave()
})

//Start an item
queue.enter()
getlongitude(completion: { (longx) in
    print("Beforelong: \(GPSlongdata)")
    print("Recieved Lat Value: \(longx)")
    GPSlongdata = GPSlongdata + longx
    print("GPSlata data is = \(GPSlongdata)") 

    //we found longdata so leave
    queue.leave()
})


//We are done with items once they BOTH finish.
queue.notify(queue: .main) {
    let skateboardposition = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: GPSlatdata, longitude: GPSlongdata)

    //just added
    let skateboardAnnotation = GPSAnnotation(coordinate: skateboardposition, title: "ACES Skaters", subtitle: "Current Board location - \nLatitude: \(GPSlatdata) Longitude: \(GPSlongdata)")

    GPSMap.addAnnotation(skateboardAnnotation)
    GPSMap.setRegion(skateboardAnnotation.region, animated: tr
}
```

References: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5371-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-2-2

Note: To test that this is the case, put a print statement after `let skateboardposition = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: GPSlatdata, longitude: GPSlongdata)` and see which ones print first... the new print statement or the ones inside the completion handlers.

Comment: Thank You, I added the print statement after the "let skateboardposition = CLLocation..." but I am still printing out 0.0 for both global variables. In my prior code, before the changes, it prints out the coordinates that I wanted just fine. And if I put "let skateboardposition... " into DispatchQueue.main.async{} my other code is unable to access that variable.

Comment: Oh whoops, minor adjustment. Look now. We can declare the variable before hand and then initialize it later in the code, if necessary. So just move the variable name out, then when we know we have all the information (inside `DispatchQueue.main.async` then we can set the variable

Comment: I added a screen shot also, thank you for helping me

Comment: I would put the entire block inside the `DispatchQueue.main.async` from `let skateboardposition...` all the way to `...GPSMap.setRegion...` and put that entire thing inside.

Comment: After you say ‘let skateboardposition = ...’ print it out. What prints?

Comment: So I made the changes that you suggested (updated above), and printed out the values as well and run a simulation to get my output but I am still getting (0.0, 0.0) for the global variables. I did a test to see if my database is retrieving the data correctly and displayed it as a label (in the screenshot), so I know the connection works fine. Any thoughts to what is still causing this ?

Comment: Where are you getting (0.0, 0.0) at? Which line shows (0.0, 0.0)?

Comment: After I add a print statement after 'let skateboardposition...' it is still printing 0.0, 0.0, just made a update above with screenshot

Comment: LOL I did it wrong - dur. Use `DispatchGroup.notify` :P Editing

Comment: I edited the line where it says `DispatchQueue.notify(queue: .main) {`. Look now and try that. My bad, I was thinking of the wrong item :P

Comment: I misused `DispatchQueue.main.async` when I should have been using `DispatchQueue.notify(queue: .main)`.

Comment: Changed it from DispatchQueue.main.async to DispatchQueue.notify(queue: .main) and xcode is telling me that  'DispatchQueue' has no member 'notify' , I'm I missing something here lol

Comment: LOL do `queue.notify` LOL im killin myself

Comment: yeah that works, I was looking at it and i noticed that also lol.

Comment: Cool cool. Had I been more prepared and mentally capable, I would have provided this answer much earlier. :P feel free to upvote and accept if it works. I provided the changes in the code

Comment: Omg, thank you for your help @impression7vx, I been scratching my head on this for days!!! Your a code beast.

Comment: Upvote and accepted done, thanks alot!!! I wish i can give u hella upvotes

Comment: Sometimes all you need is a community to answer a question. I spent around 750 rep for a question that was really simple. It happens haha

Comment: This might be a different topic, but how would I have it update the location if the location changes in realtime (firebase)?

Comment: Add another question and let me know when you do :)